# How to arrange cells in iText A4 document

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I am developing an application to generate barcode. I need a number of bar codes to be generated at a time and add to a document of A4 size, using iText Table structure. Also all the barcodes to be positioned in a 13 X 5 matrix style, that fits A4 sheet, and to be printed. But for me, the bar codes are not properly aligned and positioned. Kindly help me.

This is the code:

```
int barwidthleft=(int) 14.112;
        int barwidthtop=(int) 53.28;
        int barwidthright=(int) 16.56;
        int barwidthbottom=(int) 53.28;        
    float borderwidth=(float) 0.5;
int vgap=0;
int columns=0;
int i=0,j=0;
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4));
    Document document = new Document(pageSize);
    document.setMargins(barwidthleft, barwidthright, barwidthtop, barwidthbottom);
    try 
    {
    PdfWriter writer =PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(new File("./barcode.pdf")));
        document.open();
        int count1=0,count2=0,count3=0,count4=0;
        int maxcount=qty;
        int itemcount=0,barcount=0;
        columns=9;
        Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
        code128.setGenerateChecksum(true);
        String code="";

    while(count2<maxcount)
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columns); // 1 columns.
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPTable.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{ (float)107.28, (float)5.61,(float)107.28, (float)5.61,(float)107.28, (float)5.61,(float)107.28, (float)5.61, (float)107.28});
        table.setLockedWidth(true);
for(i=0;i<columns &&count2<maxcount;i=i+2)
        {                    
                code=Integer.toString(nextcode);
                code128.setCode(code);  
                code128.setBarHeight(30);                        
                code128.setX(1f);
                Image img=code128.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), null, null);

                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();

                cell2.setFixedHeight((float) 59.04);
                cell2.addElement(new Paragraph("Choice ",new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 6)));
                cell2.addElement(new Paragraph("Rs. "+itemlist[itemcount][4]+"/-",new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 6)));
                cell2.addElement(new Paragraph(" ",new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 2)));
                cell2.addElement(img);                           
                cell2.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(cell2);
                if(i!=8)
                {
                    PdfPCell cellblank1 = new PdfPCell();    
                    cellblank1.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                    cellblank1.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    table.addCell(cellblank1);
                }
                count2++;
                itemcount++;
                System.out.println("Two:"+count2);
                nextcode++;                    
        }
        if(count2>=maxcount)
        {
            while(i<columns)
            {
                PdfPCell finalblank1 = new PdfPCell();    
                finalblank1.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                finalblank1.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(finalblank1);

                PdfPCell finalblank2 = new PdfPCell();    
                finalblank2.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                finalblank2.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(finalblank1);
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
document.add(table);                
    }
    document.close();
//print 
    String[]args={};
    PrintPdf.main(args);
}        
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: *"But for me, the bar codes are not properly aligned and positioned."* - How are they positioned and in which way does that differ from your expectations?

Comment: Well, @mkl, the first things that catch the eye are the lines where `setHorizontalAlignment()` is used. For reasons that are documented in many places those lines only work when creating a `PdfPCell` in *text mode*, **not** in *composite mode*. I guess the OP wants to center align the content of the cells (and he's doing it wrong).